# Hex colors: Numeric representation for "transparent"?

Tags: css, colors, transparency, rgb

I am building a web CMS in which the user can choose colours for certain site elements.
I would like to convert all colour values to hex to avoid any further formatting hassle ("rgb(x,y,z)" or named colours). I have found a good JS library for that.

The only thing that I can't get into hex is "transparent". I need this when explicitly declaring an element as transparent, which in my experience can be different from not defining any value at all.

Does anybody know whether this can be turned into some numeric form? Will I have to set up all processing instances to accept hex values *or* "transparent"?  I can't think of any other way.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Transparency is a property outside the color itself, and it's also known as `alpha` component. You can't code transparency as pure RGB (which stands for red-green-blue channels), but you can use the RGBA notation, in which you define the color + alpha channel together:

```
color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); /* red at 50% opacity */
```

If you want "transparent", just set the last number to 0, regardless of the color. All of the following result in "transparent" even though the color part is set to 100% red, green and blue respectively:

```
color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0); /* transparent */
color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0); /* transparent */
color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0); /* transparent */
```

There's also the HEXA notation (or RRGGBBAA) now [supported on all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-rrggbbaa), which is pretty much the same as RGBA but using hexadecimal notation instead of decimal:

```
color: #FF000080; /* red at 50% opacity */
```

Additionally, if you just want a transparent *background*, the simplest way to do it is:

```
background: transparent;
```

You can also play with `opacity`, although this might be a tad too much and have unwanted side effects in your case:

```
.half {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* needed to support IE, my sympathies if that's the case */
}
```

Answer (score 53):

## **HEXA - #RRGGBBAA**

There's a relatively new way of doing transparency, it's called **HEXA** (HEX + Alpha). It takes in 8 digits instead of 6. The last pair is Alpha. So the pattern of pairs is **#RRGGBBAA**. Having 4 digits also works: **#RGBA**

I am not sure about its browser support for now but, you can check the **[DRAFT Docs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation)** for more information.

> ## *[§](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation)* 4.2. The RGB hexadecimal notations: #RRGGBB
>
> The syntax of a `<hex-color>` is a `<hash-token>` token **whose value consists of 3, 4, 6, or 8 hexadecimal digits**. In other words, a hex color is written as a hash character, "#", followed by some number of digits `0-9` or letters `a-f` (the case of the letters doesn’t matter - `#00ff00` is identical to `#00FF00`).
>
> ### 8 digits
>
> The first 6 digits are interpreted identically to the 6-digit notation. The last pair of digits, interpreted as a hexadecimal number, specifies the alpha channel of the color, where `00` represents a fully transparent color and `ff` represent a fully opaque color.
>
> > **Example 3**
> > In other words, `#0000ffcc` represents the same color as `rgba(0, 0, 100%, 80%)` (a slightly-transparent blue).
>
> ### 4 digits
>
> This is a shorter variant of the 8-digit notation, "expanded" in the same way as the 3-digit notation is. The first digit, interpreted as a hexadecimal number, specifies the red channel of the color, where `0` represents the minimum value and `f` represents the maximum. The next three digits represent the green, blue, and alpha channels, respectively.

For the most part, Chrome and Firefox have started supporting this:
[image]

Comment: `#0000ffcc` doesnt seem to be understood by Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 36):

The alpha channel defines the transparency value of a color, so any color is 100% transparent as long as the alpha value is 0. Typically this four-channel color type is known as RGBA.

You can specify RGBA in CSS like so:

```
div {
    background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5); /* 50% transparent */
}
```

Note that not all browsers support RGBA, in which case you can specify a *fallback*:

```
div {
    background: rgb(200, 54, 54); /* fallback */
    background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5); /* 50% transparent */
}
```

More information regarding browser support and workarounds can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/).

Answer (score 5):

You can use this conversion table: http://roselab.jhu.edu/~raj/MISC/hexdectxt.html

eg, if you want a transparency of 60%, you use 3C (hex equivalent).

This is usefull for IE background gradient transparency:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#3C545454, endColorstr=#3C545454);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#3C545454, endColorstr=#3C545454)";
```

where startColorstr and endColorstr: 2 first characters are a hex value for transparency, and the six remaining are the hex color.

Comment: Link is broken for me :(

Answer (score 3):

There are two common approaches for this: either reserve a specific color as being "transparent," in which case you cannot use that color in images without it appearing transparent, or define a fourth channel alongside red, green, and blue called "alpha" which indicates translucency/transparency.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple: no color, no opacity:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following hexadecimal code for transparent text colour: #00FFFF00

Answer (score -6):

I was also trying for transparency - maybe you could try leaving blank the value of background e.g. something like

```
bgcolor=" "
```