# Add alpha channel to hex color declared on css variable

Tags: css, variables, colors, hex, alpha

Like the title says, i would like to somehow add transparency to a hex color defined in css variable. I have seen solutions in other posts using rgb, but I need  hex.
Maybe with rgba(), calc() or linear-gradient(), but I didn't reach any result with my attempts.

Can someone help?

I couldn't find any related posts since I am using hex colors and css variables

For example:

```css
:root {
  --blue: #0000ff;
}
 
.blue-with-alpha {
  color: var(--blue)66; /* I am trying to achieve something like this */
}
```

Comment: The hexadezimal notation can't store alpha-channel information in CSS. The only browser to support such a feature were the early Internet Explorer versions, which used a set of four hexadezimal numbers, where the first one stored the alpha-channel value. (e.g. #99ffcccc) So in either case, the notation needs to be converted or you use another method to add the transparency independently of the colors alpha-channel; see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751263/hex-colors-numeric-representation-for-transparent

Comment: @feeela, I am sorry but you're wrong. I am using the notation #rrggbbaa on google chrome and it is working properly

Comment: Chrome 68 reports this as “Invalid property value”. Probably you have enabled some feature hidden behind a flag: “From version 52: this feature is behind the Enable experimental Web Platform features preference. To change preferences in Chrome, visit chrome://flags.” See also the compatibility table at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color So, **this is a relatively new feature with not-so-good- browser support**.

Comment: You can use like this `background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);`

Comment: can you show us the use case, you won't find generic solution but we can find specifc ones for your case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS hexadecimal RGBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015302/css-hexadecimal-rgba)

Comment: @feeela I tested it on firefox and it worked.
You can check this link https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation and verify that 8 digit hex is supported

Comment: It's not duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015302/css-hexadecimal-rgba, since I am using css variables

Comment: For the record: [Browser support for `#rrggbbaa` is not great](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa).

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `opacity`?

Answer (score 24):

With the new `color-mix` function, this is possible:

```css
:root {
  --blue: #0000ff;
}

.blue-with-alpha {
  background-color: color-mix(in srgb, var(--blue), transparent 66%);
}
```

```html
<p class="blue-with-alpha">Some content</p>
```

Check [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=color-mix) before using it on your project.

For more details you can check this article: https://una.im/color-mix-opacity/

Comment: Perfect one. Works for me

Answer (score 13):

There are several potential solutions to this:

• adjusting your variable to use rgb values so you can easily add an alpha in CSS:

```
:root {
   --blue: 0, 0, 255;
}

.blue-with-alpha{
   color: rgba(var(--blue), 0.44);
}
```

• you could also add alpha as a variable:

```
:root {
   --blue: 0, 0, 255;
   --alpha: .44;
}

.blue-with-alpha{
   color: rgba(var(--blue), var(--alpha);
}
```

• using opacity:

```
:root {
   --blue: #0000ff;
}

.blue-with-alpha {
   color: var(--blue);
   opacity: .44;    
}
```

• defining a different variable for your highlight:

```
:root {
   --blue: #0000ff;
   --blue-highlight: #0000ff66;
}

.blue-with-alpha{
   color: var(--blue-highlight);
}
```

Comment: Not really answering the questions :(

Comment: There is not currently a way to add to color variables in CSS like they are asking, so I am providing alternative solutions that accomplish the same.

Comment: Since your "answer" doesn't state that, it's not a valid answer, even if it's useful for some.

Comment: answered my question! Thank you @MaggieCody!

Comment: Note that `color: rgba(var(--blue), 0.44);` will only work, as in the example, with --blue being defined as rgb, not with hex values.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Safari 16.4, you can achieve it with Relative Color Syntax. But Chrome 111 and Firefox 111 haven't supported this syntax at the moment

```
.blue-with-alpha {
  color: rgb(from var(--blue) r g b / 0.4)
}
```