# Why is the shorthand hex not shorter?

Tags: css

Shorthand hex notation substitutes three character colour values for six character colours.

Why is an even shorter shorthand never implemented?

e.g. `#ff` instead of `#fff` for `#ffffff` so `#ec` can be used for `#ececec`.

Does this have something to do with the three character value being used more often than a two character value solution (e.g. `#fc0` for `#ffcc00`)?

Not trolling, honestly curious!

Comment: `#fff` doesn't actually repeat itself over twice, it's the equivalent of `#rgb` becoming `#rrggbb`.

See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colors_hex.asp

Comment: Yeah, each of the 3 digits is intended to represent red, green and blue respectively. I suspect having a 2-digit notation that repeats thrice would be confusing against the 3-digit notation. But that's speculative.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a `#f` for quick/tiny greyscale colours.

Comment: That makes me wondering why we still don't have a shorthand for hsl color system. It's much useful than rgb for design-wise

Comment: How about adding alpha `#FF0000,0.5` = `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);`

Comment: For hex transparency, there's [HEXA (#RRGGBBAA)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39718004/13138364) though not fully adopted.